# Add JSON string to sqlite in HTML5

Tags: html, sqlite

I want to add huge JSON data string in sqlite using javascript.
What should be the row definition? I tried using BLOB.
Below is my code(Here I have used small data, actually it should be large JSON string):

https://jsfiddle.net/z0nt4jhz/

```
     var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
     var msg;

     db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOGS');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log BLOB)');
        var data = [{"prodID": "2312321", "name" : "Aquaguard's latest", "imageUrl" : "/img/aqua1.jpg"},
                    {"prodID": "8457834", "name" : "pureWater", "imageUrl" : "/img/puri.jpg"}
                   ];
        var formattedString = JSON.stringify(data);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES ("productList", '+ formattedString +')', [], 
           function(){alert("success");}, 
           function(tx, err){ 
              console.log(err);
              var msz = document.querySelector('#status');
              msz.innerHTML += "<br/>ERROR: " + err.message;
              msz.innerHTML +=  "<br/>CODE:  " + err.code;
              msz.innerHTML +=  "<br/>DATABASE_ERR: " + err.DATABASE_ERR;
              msz.innerHTML +=  "<br/>CONSTRAINT_ERR: " + err.CONSTRAINT_ERR;
           }
        );
     });
```

Comment: JSON is text, so use `TEXT`. Also please use query parameters; don't concat `formattedString` to your query.

Comment: We can also have BLOB to store string. I used BLOB to store large string as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Query formation should have done as:

```
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (?, ?)', ["productList", formattedString ],
```